# How can I get the actual value of jQuery slider change event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my code for a jQuery mobile slider i would like to use the slider for navigating one page to another. please see my code.

```
<label for="slider-1">Chapter:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="1" min="1" max="2"   />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slider-1").change(function() {
        var SliderValue = $("#slider-1").val();
        console.log(slider_value)
                if(SliderValue>0){
                    //window.location = document.location+"#page"+SliderValue;
                }
        });



});
</script>
```

i just loged the variable SliderValue here i can see the value is increasing upto 295.

can any one tell me how can i get the actual value on the event?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "get the actual value on the event"? You have the value in the event!

Comment: i mean the actual value is what we can see in the textbox of slider. ican see 1 and 2 in the text box but in the event the value is going upto 285

Answer (score 1):

Supply a callback function to handle the change event as an init option.

```
$( "#slider-1" ).slider({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
       alert(ui.value);
   }
});
```

Bind to the change event by type: slidechange.

```
$( "#slider-1" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.value);
});
```

Source: [jQuery UI Slider Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change)

Comment: i tried the second one but no use
see my code
`$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#slider-1" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.value);
}); 
});`

Comment: i don't understand what you mean iam using jquerymobile not jquery ui